# How to save custom user data in Moodle

Tags: plugins, storage, moodle

I'm writing a plugin and am looking for a simple way to save some settings, per user/student. For example, I would like to store their settings in a PHP array, and then json_encode that array and save the resulting string somewhere, but not in a file. So I guess the database is the solution or a Profile field, although I think Profile fields are not intended for this purpose. Generally I'm looking for a quick solution (if that is possible), to just store one string somewhere and retrieve it, and avoid dealing with a bunch of Moodle configurations/requirements I'm not familiar with, because I don't have much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can persist your data in a DB table containing a row for each user, with a foreign key (the user id) pointing to the user table (called `userdb`, for example), containing one or more fields four your user settings.
- The table should be defined in the `your_plugin_root/db/install.xml` file and you can use the  [XMLDB Editor](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor) to safely create the table as well as to generate the code that actually creates the table in the DB.
- The generated code should be put into the `your_plugin_root/db/upgrade.php` script.

You can give a look at the XMLDB Editor in the Moodle system here:

```
HomeSite->administration->Development->XMLDB editor
```

Comment: Thanks, that went pretty smoothly thanks to the XMLDB Editor which produces the PHP code to paste inside upgrade.php. Took a while after that though because I also needed to put `global $DB;` in the upgrade code - it was missing from code examples I had found.